# Is there a way of knowing when an executable was last executed?

Tags: windows, executable

In Windows, is there a way to find out when an executable was last executed?

It seems unlikely that something like this would be saved, but I'm open for other suggestions.

It would be enough to know if it was executed "recently", for example since the computer was started, the last hour etc.

I'm open for hackish ideas, like checking the pagefile to maybe see traces left by an executable?

Comment: I once read a blog post about how Windows determines how often an exe is used (for Add/Remove programs in cpl), but it sounded very hacky and, of course, resulted in blatantly incorrect descriptions of use.  I just checked and it appears they've dropped that in Windows 7.  You could try searching for that post, I think it was on  blogs.msdn.com.

Comment: Here it is: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/09/178342.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with auditing.  Run gpedit.msc, Computer Configuration, Windows Settings, Security Settings, Advanced Audit Policy Configuration, System Audit Policies, Detailed Tracking, Audit Process Creation.  Ask more questions about it at superuser.com

Comment: (1) Can this be turned on programmatically?
(2) Does it have any negative aspects (performance?), i.e would the users of my program be upset if I turned it on when installing my app?
(3) Can the results be read programmatically?

Comment: No, possibly, yes (EventLog class).  Your installer should not mess with your client's security settings.  Logging info about programs that you don't own is suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

To be turned on programmatically:

```
auditpol.exe /set /category:"Detailed Tracking" /subcategory:"Process Creation" /success:enable /failure:enable

auditpol.exe /set /category:"Detailed Tracking" /subcategory:"Process Termination" /success:enable /failure:enable
```